# Regex Python, Match anything between A and B unless C

Tags: python, regex

A question about Regex. I have the following patterns that i want to match:

```
A()()()(B)         MATCH
A()()(B)           MATCH
A()(B)             MATCH
A(B)               MATCH
```

ALSO if anything is in the brackets apart from the phrase (NO) then that should match also:

```
A(abc)(B)          MATCH
A()(def)(B)        MATCH
A()()(ghij)(B)     MATCH
A(klmn)(opq)()(B)  MATCH
A(NO)(B)           NO MATCH
A()()(NO)(B)       NO MATCH
A(abc)(NO)(B)      NO MATCH
```

However I do not want the phrase to match if there is something that is not in the brackets:

```
Aabc(B)           NO MATCH
A()defg()(B)      NO MATCH
```

I have the following:

```
A\(.*\)*(?<!\(NO\))\(B\)
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: What if there's a bracket in the brackets? Can brackets be nested? What if there's other stuff besides `NO` in one set of brackets?

Comment: Brackets within brackets is fine just aslong as nothing is outside the brackets. ((fdsffds)dfdsfs) is fine. The (NO) is fine if it is in a nested bracket such as (dsasad(NO)) but it is not fine to have (NO(dsadwsa))

Comment: Do you need a fully 1 regex-based solution? If you do not need recursion, you can use a mere `re` regex: [`^A(\((?!NO\))[^()]*\))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/nS3hN4/1).

Comment: Not really. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Ah, I think I had an idea, but no... Something like removing all `\(([^()]*)\)` patterns and checking the contents for `NO` and the recursion level... If you need to support recursion in a regex, you would need a PyPi regex module. I just have no idea how we can check if the `(NO)` is nested or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
^A(\((?!NO\))[^)]*\))*\(B\)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH1dW0/3)

Comment: What if I also wanted it to allow for nested brackets?

Comment: Also how do i ensure what is in the final bracket is a (B)?

Comment: @ben Check my edits..matching token for `(B)` at the end added..also about the nested `()`, can `NO` be on nested `()`s?

Comment: Ahhh thats fantastic! NO can be nested as such ((NO)) but not (()NO).

Comment: @ben This is the closest i can get `^A(\((?!NO\))[^)]*(\([^)]*\))*\))*\(B\)$` ..regex is breaking on nesting..check https://regex101.com/r/rH1dW0/5

Comment: I will continue to work on it. But thank you so much, that solution works perfectly apart from the nesting issue. :)